# C# returning the correct object type

Tags: c#, generics, object, return, emgucv

```
    public Object get()
    {
        switch (current_image_type)
        {
            case(image_type.Gray):
                return (Image<Gray, Byte>)image_object;
            case(image_type.Bgr):
                return (Image<Bgr, Byte>)image_object;
            default:
                throw new Exception("No Image type set for ImageCV");
        }
    }
```

So in this get function I won't know what object type to return until run time, so I just returned the Object super class. However, this isn't good because when I get the returned Object superclass I won't have access to `Image<,>` subclass functions, unless I know what to cast it to. Is there a way for me to check what type of object `current_image_type` is return the desired object type at runtime? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `current_image_type` is a mutable property of the containing class, you simply can't know at compile time what the return type will be.

I would have `Image<T1, T2>` implement an interface like `IImage`, which encapsulates all the methods/properties that the caller(s) will need.  Then you can return a typed object:

```
public IImage get() { ... }
```

---

In the event that you can't modify `Image<T1, T2>`, you could create a kind of mediation class that would accomplish the same thing:

```
public ImageMediator<T> : IImage
{
    private readonly Image<T, Byte> _image;

    public ImageMediator(Image<T, Byte> image)
    {
        _image = image;
    }

    // TODO implement IImage
}
```

Then you can obtain an `IImage` type by simply passing `image_object` into the mediator:

```
case(image_type.Gray):
    return new ImageMediator<Gray>((Image<Gray, Byte>)image_object);
case(image_type.Bgr):
    return new ImageMediator<Bgr>((Image<Bgr, Byte>)image_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Example of checking for type Image<int,string>
        if(current_image_type.GetType() == typeof(Image<Int32,string))
            return (Image<Int32,string>)current_image_type;
```

Comment: I know this kind of thing wouldn't work in Java because of generic parameter erasure.  Don't know about C# though.

Answer (score 0):

Several different ways.  You can use the GetType() function or use the "as" operator which will cast the object to the given type if and only if it is that type.

I didn't compile this so not sure of exact syntax but you get the idea...

```
// one way
Type t = o.get().GetType();
if ( t == typeof( Image<Gray, Byte> ) {
// we have an Image<Gray, Byte>
}

// another way
Image<Gray, Byte> grb = o.get() as Image<Gray, Byte>;
if ( grb != null ) {
// we have an Image<Gray,Byte>
}
```